# How to display FontAwesome icon above WordPress menu navigation label text?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have added a FontAwesome HTML code ( `<i class="far fa-user fa-lg"></i>` ) in the WordPress navigation label section, before the title.

[image: FontAwesome icons on the left side of the menu navigation label] [image]

How to display FontAwesome icon above menu navigation label text, not left or right side?

Comment: See if this helps https://wptavern.com/how-to-add-font-awesome-icons-to-wordpress-menus

Comment: If you don't want 1 more plugin to run your site for such litlle improvement you can append the icon via JS.